# C++: Making a DLL accessible to multiple processes concurrently

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, dll

I have created a DLL in C++ VS2010.

It seems to me that 2 programs can not access it at the same time. 
First program 1 has to complete the calls to the DLL, only then the DLL will process the calls from the other program.

I would like to know if there is a certain switch in the project settings that I need to set to make the DLL "multi-threaded".

The DLL is used by Windows SAPI. A program (in my case two programs) can reference the SAPI and make a computer voice (the computer voice is the DLL) speak something. I expected both programs to speak at the same time, but since they don't (they wait for each other), I expected my DLL to be single-threaded.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you are doing?  There should be no reason why two programs can't both use the same DLL at the same time.  Each one will load the DLL into its own memory space and execute the code independently.  On a modern OS, neither process will have any knowledge of or access to the other process.

Comment: There are reasons why it could appear as tmighty describes.  It could be doing a bunch of stuff while holding the loader lock.  It could also be synchronizing on a named event or other synchronization primitive.  We have no way of knowing with the information given.  But my money is on the loader lock.

Comment: @MicahCaldwell The DLL is used by Windows SAPI. A program (in my case two programs) can reference the SAPI and make a computer voice (in my case the DLL) speak something. I expected both programs to speak at the same time, but since they don't (they wait for each other), I expected my DLL to be single-threaded.

Comment: @jeffamaphone What is a "loader lock"???

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173266.aspx there you can get some causes of loader locks

Comment: Given this new info it doesn't sound like the loader lock.  It seems more like it is trying to access the audio device exclusively, or for some reason only one process can access the device at a time.  This is outside my domain of knowledge, but I think we can all agree that the issue is not how the DLL was compiled.  It will require further investigation into the contentious code paths.

Comment: To test What Jeffamaphone just commented I would put the programs in two different folders with two different copies of your DLL.  that way if it still doesn't work you know for sure its not problem loading the DLLs and a problem with using the Device at the same time or something similar

Answer (score 4):

The speech API serializes speech from multiple sources so they don't play at the same time.  One will play first, then the next, and so on until there is no more pending speech to be played.  You can disable this via the registry as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431801(v=vs.85).aspx#_Toc494873956

Particularly the `NoSerializeAccess` value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Speech\AudioOutput\<AudioOutput1>\Attributes` where `<AudioOutput1>` is the name of your audio output device.

This information can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/speechplatform_ispaudio.aspx

> In order to prevent multiple TTS voices or engines from speaking simultaneously, the Speech Platform serializes output to objects which implement the ISpAudio interface. To disable serialization of outputs to an ISpAudio object, place an attribute called "NoSerializeAccess" in the Attributes folder of its object token.